# How can I authenticate my user to log-in in Laravel?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I'm **stuck** trying to authenticate my user to log-in in Laravel 5.

---

## I have

```
  $user = User::where('code','=', Input::get('code'))->first();
  $password = Input::get('password');
  $user->password = Hash::make($password);
  $user->code   =  $code;
  $user->username = Input::get('username');
  $user->active = 1;
  $user->save();
```

`$auth = Auth::attempt(['username' => $user->username, 'password' => $user->password, 'active' => 1]);`

when I do `dd($auth);`, It print out `false`.

---

It wired because I check my database, that user is there with :

- username
- password
- active = 1

What did I do wrong here ?
Is it sth that they change in Laravel 5 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't hash the password before you send it to the `attempt()` function.  It will hash it again and compare it against the single hashed version.

Try this...

```
$auth = Auth::attempt(['username' => $user->username, 'password' => Input::get('password'), 'active' => 1]);
```